# how to set the value of multiple checkbox of the userform to a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

**Situation:**
I have a userform as shown below:

[image: Userform with 3 checkbox]

**current solution**
when i click OK, the following result is displayed
[image: current result from the checkbox]

That means the checkbox values are stored in individual cells.

**desired solution**
Can I possibly modify my code such that the value is entered in a single cell for example like in the following picture with various combinations of the checkbox result is shown.
[image: desired result from the userform]

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2).Value = "Checked" Else Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 15).Value = ""
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 3).Value = "Forwarded" Else Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 14).Value = ""
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 4).Value = "Notified" Else Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 16).Value = ""
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to build a string in a variable and then populate the cell with it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim Value as String
  If CheckBox1.Value Then Value = "Checked"
  If CheckBox3.Value Then Value = Value & IIf(Value = "", "", " / ") & "Forwarded"
  If CheckBox4.Value Then Value = Value & IIf(Value = "", "", " / ") & "Notified"
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2).Value = Value
End Sub
```

Note the use of [IIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function) to determine whether to conditionally add the separator (`" / "`) when appropriate, rather than trying to trim it off later.

Comment: Thank you @user51 for the solution. I tired the above recommendation but it still doesnt meet my solution. The combinations dont give an output as shown in the "desired result from the userform" picture.

Comment: Likely because I originally wrote `Value = IIf(...`, instead of `Value = Value & IIf(...`, so they weren't cumulative.  Edited.  Perhaps this version will meet your needs instead?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct. It actually does what I want. I tired it again using `Value= Value & IIF(..` . 
Perfect solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Vicky If you think the solution is correct, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the optimal solution that i could find. I look forward for corrections but so far it works according to my needs.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim Value As String
      If CheckBox1.Value Then Value = "Checked"
      If CheckBox3.Value Then Value = "Forwarded"
      If CheckBox1.Value And CheckBox3.Value Then Value = IIf(Value = "", "", "Checked/") & "Forwarded"
      If CheckBox4.Value Then Value = "Notified"
      If CheckBox3.Value And CheckBox4.Value Then Value = IIf(Value = "", "", "Forwarded/") & "Notified"
      If CheckBox1.Value And CheckBox4.Value Then Value = IIf(Value = "", "", "Checked/") & "Notified"
      If CheckBox1.Value And CheckBox3.Value And CheckBox4.Value Then Value = IIf(Value = "", "", "Checked/Forwarded") & "Notified"
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2).Value = Value
    
    End Sub
```

Thank you.